# Uploading to BrickFTP via cURL contains content disposition headers

Tags: php, curl, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload a file to [BrickFTP](https://developers.brickftp.com/) using their API with the PHP cURL library. I am able to upload the file but the content disposition headers end up at the top of the uploaded file. (BrickFTP uploads to Amazon S3). My question is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47134792/uploading-file-to-brickftp-using-dropzone) but I wasn't able to convert that answer PHP.

```
// Authenticate with Session
$ch = curl_init();
$postData = json_encode([
   'username' => 'xxx',
   'password' => 'xxx'
]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://SUBDOMAIN.brickftp.com/api/rest/v1/sessions.json");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ["Content-Type: application/json", "Accept: application/json"]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$error = curl_error($ch);

$result = json_decode($result);
$apiID = $result->id;

// Step 1: Get the upload URI
$remotePath = 'https://SUBDOMAIN.brickftp.com/api/rest/v1/files/' . basename($this->remotePath);
$postData = json_encode([
   'action' => 'put',
]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $remotePath);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "BrickAPI={$apiID}");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$error = curl_error($ch);

$result = json_decode($result);
$headers = empty($result->headers) ? 0 : $result->headers;

// Step 2: Upload the file
$fileSize = filesize($this->localPath);
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$finfo = finfo_file($finfo, $this->localPath);
$cFile = new CURLFile($this->localPath, $finfo, basename($this->localPath));
$postData = ['file' => $cFile];
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $result->upload_uri);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ["Content-Length: {$fileSize}", "Content-Type: text/plain"]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, $fileSize);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$error = curl_error($ch);

// Step 3: Complete the request
...
```

The file gets uploaded successfully, but with this added to the top:

```
--------------------------af8ccf12ca11d3f7
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="0"; filename="my-file.csv"
Content-Type: text/plain
```

At first I had `Content-type` set to `multipart/form-data` but Googling around, I read that some people fixed the issue by setting the `Content-type` to `text/plain`; that didn't work for me. I also tried using just `@/filepath/my-file.csv` as the value for `file` in `$postData` but that resulted in an `HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like I just needed to send in the data as a string like so:

```
$postData = file_get_contents($this->localPath);
```

Maybe a duplicate of: [PHP Curl post a file without header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21887946/php-curl-post-a-file-without-header)